# Does "\root" do anything in /etc/aliases?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I've found on a couple servers that have the following entry in `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: \root,email@example.com
```

You can send mail to `/dev/null` like this:

```
root: /dev/null
```

I can't find `\root` used in any documentation.

1. Does `\root` do anything?
2. Could it be a syntax error?

Comment: You seem to be right that the backslash syntax does not appear to be documented in "man 5 aliases" where one would expect it to be mentioned (or at least I cannot find it in my section 5 aliases man page) but this is a longstanding feature of the mail aliases file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 but I can't find what the \ does
```

The backslash "escapes" the token following, preventing further interpretation.

It's an important mechanism in defining aliases like the example in your post, where "root" is aliased to include both the account of that name AND other addresses.  Without the \ a loop would be created when the program interpreting the alias tried to dereference "root", which includes as a member "root" (which includes as a member "root", and so on..)

Comment: Just to be clear: it is used when an account forwards to itself, as root does above? (And the purpose is to prevent a loop?)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `\root` prevents that id from being passed through aliases again and (instead is) delivered to the LOCAL root account.

Answer (score 3):

`\root` will save the message to (for example) `/var/mail/root` and forward it to `email@example.com`. Without it, only `email@example.com` will receive the message. The `\user, other@address` notation is very common for users that use `~/.forward` files.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a backslash (\) in front of the username in the first recipient is a special syntax for delivering mail to the local mail spool with no further aliasing.

```
root: \root,email@example.com
```

Here, user `root` is forwarding mails to two different places:

1. One copy of the message goes to the mail spool
2. The second recipient, email@example.com, sends another copy of message to MX servers of example.com

Please find details [here](http://www.bga.org/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/mail/aliasing/).